# How to generate outputs in xml from Nagios?

Tags: xml, nagios

is it possible to generate nagios output files in xml format?
if there is a way, how to do it?
I have a code that generate outputs in pdf, but now I try to have a xml format, is it possible with PNP4Nagios?

Comment: What do you mean by "Nagios output files"? Output of current problems / alerts? PNP4nagios is for graphing.

Comment: thank you @AdamvonNieda for your request, I want to generate Excel, it ok